# Oauth2.0 and confusion about Google service account

Tags: php, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, service-accounts

I am trying to create a website where a user will sign up with a master user name and password, along with their Google analytics. When they log in with the master account they will automatically be logged in to view their GA data ( as well as data from other APIs).

I am currently trying to run HelloAnalytics.php I have created a service account and generated the client secret file. The file is read but I get the following error

> "Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts: (403) User does not have any Google Analytics account

I have read that to fix this you must add the service account email to the GA account you wish to view. I am confused on if this is true and how the service account works as there is only a 1 page guide online. Will all the users who wish to use my website have to add the service account email to their GA accounts? Or am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the service account is that it is not for a person, but for an serverside application (the service).

Your users would authenticate against your service (with whatever authentication scheme you provide yourself), and the service would authenticate against Google Analytics using the credentials from the service account.

The service account needs to be added to all accounts that your service wants to draw data from, as the service account is the "user" for which access is granted.

However it seems you do not need a service account at all; if the users trust you with their data they can provide any email/password combo that is added to their accounts, and you can use that to log in.

Comment: How would I log them in without using the service account? Would I use the client Id instead? I am confused on how I would access their information specifically. I am very new to using google API

Comment: You should read over the various auth scenarios listed here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#scenarios but it is clear to me that you want to set up a web application which means you should follow the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-php